# creating date with different zones in java8

Tags: java-8, zoneddatetime

I am trying to create `Date` object with US timezone from system default timezone.

I am using java 8 new date time APIs. To create date object I am making use of
`Calendar` API. Is there any way I can create `Date` object with out `Calendar`?

The below code is working as expected but just want to know if there are any other better ways.

```
ZonedDateTime timeZone = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
            new Date().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
timeZone = timeZone.withZoneSameInstant((ZoneId
        .of("America/Anchorage")));
// Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(timeZone.getYear(),
        timeZone.getMonthValue() - 1,
        timeZone.getDayOfMonth(),
        timeZone.getHour(), timeZone.getMinute());
Date usDate = c.getTime();
System.out.println(usDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

- No such thing as “Date object with US timezone”. A `Date` is always in UTC.
- Avoid legacy date-time classes. Use only java.time classes.
- Applying a time zone to a moment in UTC does *not* alter its meaning, still the same point on the timeline.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Do not mix the java.time classes with the notoriously troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Avoid the legacy classes *entirely*.

This has been presented many many times already on Stack Exchange. Please search before posting. I'll do only a brief recap here.

Current moment in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with resolution  of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Anchorage" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

You may be failing to understand that applying the time zone does *not* change the meaning. The zone merely allows for looking at this value through the lens of a particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time). But both the `instant` and the `zdt` in this example represent the very same moment, the **very same point on the timeline**.

### Convert

If you must have a `java.util.Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated for java.time types, convert. To convert to/from java.time using new methods added to the old classes.

> trying to create Date object with US timezone

No such thing. A `java.util.Date` is always in UTC by definition.

The equivalent of `java.util.Date` in java.time is `Instant`. You can convert but beware of data-loss with nanoseconds versus milliseconds resolution in the fractional second.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Do all your real work in java.time. Avoid the legacy classes as much as possible (they are a bloody nightmare).